# what is a lords son expected to do in the medieval times

Tags: medieval

I'm trying to put myself in the shoes of a lord and what my children are expected to be or do but I dont know what they should do.Please help as much as possible?

Comment: I think you need to do a little internet research and the refine your question a bit to your specific fantasy setting.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a worldbuilding question.  It seems like a history question, and an extremely broad one at that.

Comment: This would probably be better asked on History.SE. That said, my offhand guess is "learn to be the next Lord". Presumably the son is expected to take over when the father dies or wants to retire. They're also probably expected to learn to fight. A *modern-day* Lord's son would be expected to attend diplomatic ceremonies such as breaking ground for important construction, giving speeches, etc., but not sure that sort of thing existed in medieval times.

Answer (score 1):

For medieval England, the traditional rule was: first son inherits (primogeniture), second son becomes a soldier, third son goes into the priesthood. The second son was essentially a backup for the first, who might well die. In addition to the usual hazards of childhood, medieval lords were bound by fealty to a higher lord or king, and would provide fighting men upon demand. The lord or his heir would be expected to lead such a contingent, so the chances of dying in battle (or of wounds) was not negligable. Younger sons had no particular expectation of inheriting, and were generally literate, so the priesthood was the obvious occupation.

If such a rule were not enforced, and all of the sons spent their time hanging around waiting for their father to die, they might well spend a good deal of time plotting and rebelling against their father and each other. I suggest you read up on Henry II, (1133 - 1189), whose 5 sons were a constant source of trouble. Or, for an entertaining fictional take on the issue, Neil Gaiman's "Stardust". Once a son inherited a title, it was not a good idea to keep his younger brothers around, since there would always be the temptation to go for the brass ring and rebel or plot to discredit the king. Another historical example you should read up on is Elizabeth I/Mary, Queen of Scots.

If you want, you can always write about a younger brother who supports his older brother wholeheartedly. Just be aware that this requires a rather Pollyanna-ish take on human nature. The current, very civilized, rules about royal succession are a historical anomaly, and they work in large part because constitutional monarchs don't have much real power compared with monarchs in olden time. To some degree this will be muted in subordinate lords (dukes, counts, etc), since a threatened lord can call on his liege lord for assistance, which would make any successful rebellion by a son rather unlikely unless he moves very swiftly and decisively.